# why my spark streaming job getting slower

Tags: python, cassandra, apache-spark, spark-streaming, pyspark

I have a job that receives data from Kafka every 10s, and then I format the data and insert into cassandra, but it's very confusing that my job get slower and slower.

According to my statitics, there are less than 100 messages every 10s and at the first time, the processing just takes at most 1 second, but after several days the processing get slower and it needs 14 seconds to process a 10 seconds' data now.

I'm puzzled if there were some factor that would make the job slower.

And I notice that the processing `python -m pyspark.daemon` also costs more and more memory, are there some methods to reduce the memory cost.

```
PID   USER      PR   NI VIRT    RES     SHR  S  %CPU %MEM   TIME+ COMMAND 

24527 yao.yu    20   0 10.334g 9.823g   3580 R  96.8 66.9   3424:56 python
```

the code is as follow:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Kafka_To_Cassandra").set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition", "1000")
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)

    brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:] 

    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers, "auto.offset.reset": "smallest"})
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1]) \
           .filter(lambda s: 'identifier' in s) \
           .filter(lambda s: 'app_name' in s) \
           .filter(lambda s: 'app_version' in s)
    map_lines = lines.map(mapper).filter(lambda s: 'JsonLoadException' not in s)
    #map_lines.pprint()
    map_lines.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreachPartition(save_to_cassandra))

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: It's hard to say why the process accumulated memory like this without seeing your code.

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak: If your or some other application is using memory and not releasing it then after some time this "leaked" memory will grow significantly larger than your physical RAM which would force the machine to make use of disk paging to supplement the RAM which has a very negative effect on performance. A reboot or just a process restart is a quick fix but not a solution.

Comment: @KlausD. Hi Klaus, the code is posed above, i think the reason may be: 
    `kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers, "auto.offset.reset": "smallest"})`

Answer (score 0):

this configuration may help you.

spark.cleaner.ttl

Duration (seconds) of how long Spark will remember any metadata (stages generated, tasks generated, etc.). Periodic cleanups will ensure that metadata older than this duration will be forgotten. This is useful for running Spark for many hours / days (for example, running 24/7 in case of Spark Streaming applications). Note that any RDD that persists in memory for more than this duration will be cleared as well.

Comment: Please include a link from where these text are copied. Thank you.

Comment: @Pang the above text is linked [Execution Behavior](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior)

Comment: @tao.meng I'm not clear that if the accumulated metadata would effect the performace of Spark Streaming job, as well as the memory cost of pyspark.daemon. would you like give me some more details, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use Scala to write my code again, using [Spark-Cassandra-Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector).

I'm sure that the connection of Cassandra costs much memory, so the official Doc of Spark Streaming [Design Patterns for using foreachRDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd) suggests you to make a connection pool so that you don't have to construct a connection every time for eachRDD or foreachPartition. But i don't have a good idea how to make python-cassandra-driver to support that.

I reconstruct my code using Scala, Spark-Cassandra-Connector supports Spark Streaming pretty well. Then my job works stably for several weeks even months without memory leak.